# If class contains string jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove all the events not related to current post.

In this code snippets, both example works, but on my site only the manually version work.
jQuery is installed on my website (3.6.0). I just can't figure out why it's not working.

```js
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var myTitle =  $('h1').text().toLowerCase();
    var newTitle = myTitle.replace(" ", "-");
    
    // Using Var - Not working on my site
    $(".news-archive.1 .news-item").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('class').indexOf(newTitle) > -1) {
            $(this).addClass('show1');        
        }
    });

    // Manually typing indexOf, this works.
    $(".news-archive.2 .news-item").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('class').indexOf('walt-disney') > -1) {
            $(this).addClass('show2');        
        }
    });
 
 
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.show1 {
  color: pink;
}

.show2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Walt Disney</h1>

<div class="news-archive 1">
  <div class="news-item category_item-walt-disney">Walt Disney 1</div>
  <div class="news-item category_item-walt-disney">Walt Disney 2</div>
  <div class="news-item category_item-nike-sports">Nike Sports</div>
  <div class="news-item category_item-virgin-arlines">Virgin Airlines</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="news-archive 2">
  <div class="news-item category_item-walt-disney">Walt Disney 1</div>
  <div class="news-item category_item-walt-disney">Walt Disney 2</div>
  <div class="news-item category_item-nike-sports">Nike Sports</div>
  <div class="news-item category_item-virgin-arlines">Virgin Airlines</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please describe the expected behaviour and then what actually happens?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). If you can't replicate the problem here, we won't be able to help you solve it. Use the debugger built into your IDE and/or browser and step through the code, seeing where it fails.

Comment: On your site: what's the result of `console.log("[" + newTitle + "]", newTitle.length)` (just after `var newTitle=`)?  You *probably* just want: `$('h1').text().toLowerCase().trim()`

Comment: @phuzi it marks all news that have a category that contains the name of the h1.

Comment: Also, you *probably* don't want to parse `.attr("class")` as it's possible/likely to get false positives.  Instead, use `$(".category_item-" + newTitle).addClass('show1');`

Comment: @freedomn-m - Somethings not clean.. https://go.seee.link/chrome_XSuNYY27in.png I'm new in jQuery so didn't think of that.

Comment: So your `h1` doesn't contain what you think it does ... *or*... you have more than one `h1` and `.text()` combines them all into a single text - try `$("h1").first().text()...`  (and `console.log($("h1").length)`).  Might be an idea to give your `h1` its own class for the one you want, eg `<h1 class="title">` then `$("h1.title")` - you might still have more than one if you have multiple "sections" so would need more targeted selector; would need to see more html to help with that.

Comment: @freedomn-m - You were right.. There was to h1 on the site.. #multipledevs .. Thank you for clear mind.. THIS IS NOW SOLVED 